# Setup CircleCi to trigger build on pull request AND on changes to specific branches

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

Using "Only build Pull Requests" works for pull requests and changes to the default branch only, I need to trigger builds on specific branches too.

1. Creating a PR to any branch - trigger build
2. Push changes to develop,master and release branches - trigger build
3. Push changes to any other branches - do not trigger build